# Conditional contact formula (in Wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form, wufoo

I've Googled around for about an hour, without luck.

I'm trying to build an advanced contact formula i a Wordpress environment. The contact formula should do this:

At first, there should only be a single dropdown-menu available, like this:

```
Option1
Option2
Option3
```

If 'Option1' is selected, then some information should be shown, and then another dropdown-menu is shown, as such:

```
Option4
Option5
Option6
```

If 'Option2' is selected, then it should again show some information, but then show three other options, like this:

```
Option7
Option8
Option9
```

And so on. Many survey-formulars are built in this way - but I need to make it, to make a support-site for some different products.

I tried Googling for Wordpress-plugins, but without any luck (I must admit, I'm unsure of, what I should search for). I've used Wufoo-formula's before, but it doesn't appear to me, that Wufoo has that option. 
   How is this made the easiest and the best? Hand-coding it using HTML, javascript and CSS? Or are there a cool online-tool that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and made some research, which ended up in some results.

**1. Buy the required functions**
If you have a great number of forms to create and the money to invest, you could use something like Ninja Forms and buy the Conditional Logic plugin. With this you can create multiple forms and connect their elements with the needed criteria to show or hide them or to change their values.
https://ninjaforms.com/extensions/conditional-logic/

**2. Code the form**
Actually we have only one form we use. This is the reason, because I decided to save my money and did it myself.
I expanded our wordpress theme by another page template and created the form that fits our needs in it. After that I added the PHP code to send the form via email on the top and the JavaScript code for the conditional logic on the bottom of my php file. In Wordpress I created a new page and applied the newly created page template.

I'm not sure if this is best practice, but for me it was an easy way to achieve my goal and save some time.

Best regards